# Angular2 decorator for 2 way property binding

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angularjs-bindings

From Victor Savkin's post on [Angular2 template syntax](http://victorsavkin.com/post/119943127151/angular-2-template-syntax), shows how to use input and output property binding -

```
<todo-cmp [model]="todo" (complete)="onCompletingTodo(todo)"></todo-cmp>

@Component({selector: 'todo-cmp'})
class TodoCmp {
  @Input() model;
  @Output() complete = new EventEmitter(); // TypeScript supports initializing fields
}
```

The input property is decorated with @Input() while output property has @Output().
How should I declare a property which is going to have a 2 way property binding?
Example: Assuming rootpanel component has 'suggestions' property (of type string) and searchPanel has 'getSuggestions property. Now I want the two properties to be bound to each other both ways. 
I tried -

**rootpanel.html:**

```
<search-panel [(getSuggestions)]="suggestions"> </search-panel>
```

But I am stuck while declaring the getSuggestions property in the searchPanel component. 
Also what should be the type of the getSuggestions property - `string or EventEmitter<string>`?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want two-way model binding from the parent component:

```
[(model)]
```

You need the following in your child component:

```
@Input() model: string;
@Output() modelChange:EventEmitter<string>;
```

At some point when the model is overwritten in your child component, you'll emit the `modelChange` event:

```
updateModel(newValue:string) {
    this.model = newValue;
    this.modelChange.emit(this.model);
}
```

From the parent component's perspective, `[(model)]` is equivalent to:

```
[model]="model"  (modelChange)="model=$event"
```

In this way, when the model property changes inside a child component, the change in the model propagates upwards though two-way binding, synching all the bound models along the way.

Comment: Thanks, for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `[(getSuggestions)]`-style for two-way-binding declare the fields like

```ts
class TodoCmp {
  @Input() getSuggestions;
  @Output() getSuggestionsChange = new EventEmitter(); 

  onClick() {
    getSuggestions = 'someValue';
    getSuggestionsChange.emit(getSuggestions);
  }
}
```

`getSuggestions` is probably not a good choice for such a input/output combination but it should demonstrate how they are connected. The output needs to have the same name as the input with an additional `Change`.
If this naming scheme doesn't fit use your component like

```ts
<search-panel [suggestions]="suggestions" (getSuggestions)="updateSuggestions($event)> </search-panel>
```

with input/output like

```ts
class TodoCmp {
  @Input() suggestions;
  @Output() getSuggestions = new EventEmitter(); 

  onClick() {
    suggestions = 'someValue';
    getSuggestions.emit(getSuggestions);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped.

Answer (score 0):

The approach pixelbits recommended is exactly how you should do that, but if you have multiple two-way data binding properties on a component, or even one that changes frequently in your codebase, I created a decorator for that.
If you are using npm [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/two-way-decorator) it is.
Just go to the gihub page if you need the code.

With this, you can directly use:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TwoWay } from 'two-way-decorator';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss']
})
export class ExampleComponent {
 
  @TwoWay()
  public text: string;
 
  @TwoWay()
  public count: number;
 
}
```